# Can I get the actual Excel row number of Excel spreadsheet row (not a sequential calculated number)

Tags: c#, excel

I am processing a multi-tab spreadsheet and saving the rows in a SQL database.  I would like to store the actual Excel row number (that shows in the first column before column A).  I have tried a number of ways to accomplish this but cannot seem to find a method that works.  My current sample code is shown below.  I would like to avoid counting rows as they are read from the file but would rather just get the actual Excel row number from Excel.  I am hope I am explaining this adequately.  I may only process 1 of every 5 or 10 rows and would have thought there would be a way to retrieve the row number that Excel displays to the left of Column A.  Is that possible or am I out of luck?  The code below seems to display only a sequential number of (for example) 1 through 5 if I only process 5 records.  I am not doing any restriction of rows anywhere else in the code.  I realize the following code is simplistic but it accurately reflects what I am trying to do.

```
foreach (IXLWorksheet works in workBook.Worksheets)
{
    //  get the name of the worksheet (the tab name)
    string worksName = works.Name;
    foreach (IXLRow row in works.Rows())
    {
        bProcessThisRow = false;
        if (rowcontents == userrequest)
        {
            bProcessThisRow = true;
        }
        //  more determination of rowcontents to user spec's
        if (bProcessThisRow)
        {
            //  get the Excel number of this row
            int iRowNum = row.RowNumber();
            //  save row contents in database record
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example where the row number is not what you expect it to be? `RowNumber()` will return the number of the row. If it's row 1, it will return 1. If it's row 10, it will return 10. Is that not what's happening, and if not, what is happening?

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is embarrassing but I have to tell the truth because anything other than that would be "read" by everyone...yesterday was a really hectic day (I know, we all have them) and I just plain fouled up on the test data file.  It was no one's fault but my own.  And Scott Hannen was correct, RowNumber() does return the correct response.  This was my first experience using the RowNumber() feature and a lack of faith in myself/experience with the RowNumber() probably contributed.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It would probably be better suited to delete the question.  Since the question doesn't really have an "answer" per se, that can't really help anyone.